# Filtering records in a table with Google Analytics & OOCharts

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently trying to display the google analytics data onto my website using a plugin named [OOCharts](http://oocharts.org/) . It works fine, just that I cannot filter the records populated in the table. I've learnt that I need to use the .setFilter() function on a OO.Query object but I have no idea how to pass the filtered query to the OO.Table object. Please input if anyone knows anything on this, and here's my code till now:

```
oo.setOOId("<My OOID here>");
var from = "01/01/2011";

var today = new Date();

var to = today;

oo.load(doCharts());
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

});

function doCharts() {
    var q = new oo.Query("<My Profile ID here>", new Date("1/7/2013"), new Date("3/30/2013"));
    q.addDimension('ga:pageTitle');
    q.setFilter('ga:pageTitle==<my Filter string>');

    var t = new oo.Table("<My Profile ID here>", new Date(from), new Date(to));

    t.addMetric("ga:pageviews", "Page views");
    t.addDimension(q); //this doesn't seem right :/
    t.setOption('page', 'enable');
    t.setOption('pageSize', '20');
    t.draw('table1');

    q.execute(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually set the filter on the query that feeds the table like this:

```
var t = new oo.Table("<My Profile ID here>", new Date(from), new Date(to));

t.query.setFilter('ga:pageTitle==<my Filter string>'); 

//Go on to draw and add other params
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Just to clarify, you don't even need the query object on top. The table actually creates on when it is constructed, so you can just use the setFilter method on the table's query. All OOcharts objects have the query under them, and can be manipulated before drawing like shown above: *t.query.someMethod()*

Comment: Omg! That worked like a charm. Thank you so much. You've been of great help! Good day to you :)